# SQL Server Import/Export Data Wizard vs DTExec for Excel Dates

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, dts

I'm trying to create an Excel spreadsheet using the latest SSDT inside Visual Studio 2015 as a SQL Server 2014 project/package.  I first used the SQL Server Import/Export Data Wizard to run and create a DTS package that issues a simple query to retrieve data from a SQL Server database table which includes a DATETIME columnn and export this to Excel, preserving the DATETIME column as a DATE in Excel.

Running the DTS package during the wizard correctly creates the Excel file with the column value as a DATE.  But when I re-run the DTS package that the wizard saved to the file system using Visual Studio 2015 (using 32-bit mode) or ANY 32-bit version of the DTExec utility, the Excel file is always created with the column value as TEXT.  The Excel sheet is created using the 'DateTime' type and the internal SSIS type is DT_DBTIMESTAMP.  I'm using the Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 32-bit driver as I have Office 2016 32-bit installed on my developer workstation (although likely will be using the 64-bit version on production server).

Any thoughts on why the difference occurs when running it using the wizard vs. running it in Visual Studio or using DTExec?  This is driving me crazy!

Or does anyone have any different approaches to forcing this column to be a DATE in Excel?

Thanks!

Bryan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exporting `date` records to excel via SSIS will always be treated as `TEXT`, unless you have dummy records in your excel sheet already, then import to that excel right after dummy rows. Assume you have dummy rows set to `DATE` format

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  Does the wizard create these dummy records, which isn't included in the DTS package it creates?  Is that how it works but running the created DTS package doesn't?  If so, why don't I see the dummy records in the output file?

Comment: that is probably done internally when using the DTS package via sql server, not sure what is the internal logic it is using to treat those records, but you have to create dummy rows with specific data type ahead before you need the output as the same data type in SSIS.

Comment: Can you point me to any samples online?  I'm assuming the Excel file must be created beforehand with the dummy row but the wizard creates the file.  I don't know how, though.  The DTS package has a Prepare SQL statement that issues a CREATE Table 'Sheet1' query to create the sheet in the Excel spreadsheet.  This statement fails if the file already exists with that sheet.  So I don't know how the dummy records would be created beforehand.  And how would you remove the dummy records?

Comment: For the dummy rows, you have to manually put ahead. I am not sure whether there is such a document. But here is what you could do: open excel ;  goes to sheet1 ; put 01/01/1990 in the first cell of column A ; then highlight the entire column A, change the type to DATE ; after that using data flow task to import DATE records after row#1 in column A ; any DATE you insert into sheet1 after the first cell will be DATE format ; and the best way to handle the dummy rows is to manually delete them.

Comment: I implemented your proposed solution and it works as expected, notwithstanding the fact that I have to create a dummy formatting row.  As I implemented it, I realized I had done this many years ago to solve the same problem.  I guess time doesn't address everything!  Deleting the dummy rows doesn't really work for me since I would need to install the Excel interop libraries on our production server, so I just hid the row.  I've marked your reply as the answer, for now.  Would still like to find a way to do this without a dummy formatting row.

Comment: Much appreciate your suggestion to hide the dummy rows xD, still,I am looking for a better to achieve the same goal in ssis as well. Thank you, too